# Angular2 access parent component's @input values

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-components

I'm trying to load a component dynamically using the ComponentResolver and ViewContainerRef services.

The child component loads ok and the template is rendered. However i want to access the inputs from the parent ('field' and 'values') inside the child component.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Parent component:

```
import {Component, Input, ViewChild, ComponentFactory, ViewContainerRef, ComponentResolver} from '@angular/core';
import {MyInputComponent} from './my-input.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-field',
    template: `
        <label class="control-label">
            <span>{{field.label}}</span>
            <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div #target></div>
    `
})
export class MyFieldComponent {

    @Input() field;
    @Input() values;

    @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.compiler.resolveComponent(MyInputComponent).then((factory: ComponentFactory<any>) => {
            this.target.createComponent(factory);
        });
    }

    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: ComponentResolver) {
    }

}
```

Child component:

```
import {Component, Input, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-input',
    template: `
        This is an input component!!!
    `
})
export class MyInputComponent {

    @Input() field: any;
    @Input() values: any;


    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this);
    }

    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you can leverage something like this:

```
this.compiler.resolveComponent(MyInputComponent).then((factory: ComponentFactory<any>) => {
   let component = this.target.createComponent(factory);
   component.instance.field = this.field;
});
```

See also the example https://plnkr.co/edit/bdGYvTf8y9LEw9DAMyN1?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. I've been trying to get my head around the ComponentResolver now that DynamicComponentLoader has been deprecated.