# How to pass input and output parameters in Angular2 rc4 in dynamically created component

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a component which wanted to pass a several parameter:

```
 <sentence [sentence]="text.title" [selectedWord]="selectedWord" (selectionChanged)="selectionChanged($event)"></sentence>
```

I'm creating a component dynamically using this code:

```
 addComponent() {
        this.compiler.resolveComponent(TaskHeaderComponent).then((factory) =>

        this.cmpRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory, 0, this.viewContainer.injector));
    }
```

How i can pass to created component:

1. inputs: [sentence]="text.title" [selectedWord]="selectedWord"
2. outputs function: (selectionChanged)="selectionChanged($event)"

TIA

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368107/angular2-access-parent-components-input-values/37370695#37370695

Comment: yes, only way - to get access to cmpRef.instance and set inputs in code, subscribe for outputs manually also..

Answer (score 1):

There is no binding support dor dynamically added elements, but you can do it imperatively

```
this.cmpRef.instance.sentence = ...
this.cmpRef.instance.selectionChange.subscribe(...)
```